# Update two editor instance showing same file

Tags: java, editor, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have eclipse rcp application, editor with ctabfolder in certain scenerio i am having editor instance further ctabfolder page those are showing file content. My problem is that if i opened same file in first editor and afer change made at file i opened another editor at application, now it showing the previous opened file not the updated one while i have made avaliable changed file for all process for opening another ediotr.

I am using this for creating editor input, I think this is culprit as it is in a singleton pattern and returning the already invoked instance of ctab page.

```
IFileStore fileStore = EFS.getLocalFileSystem().getStore("filepath");
```

if yes then tell me the appropriate replacement for this.

Answer (score 0):

To make an editor be aware that the file it is editing has been changed by another editor you need to make the editor track resource changes using an `IResourceChangeListener`. Set this up with something like:

```
IResourceChangeListener resourceChange = new ResourceChange();

ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(resourceChange, IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE);
```

The `ResourceChange` class would be:

```
private class ResourceChange implements IResourceChangeListener
{
  @Override
  public void resourceChanged(final IResourceChangeEvent event)
  {
    final IResourceDelta eventDelta = event.getDelta();

    final IResourceDelta trackDelta = eventDelta.findMember(editFile);
    if (trackDelta != null)
     {
       if ((trackDelta.getKind() & IResourceDelta.CHANGED) != 0 &&
           (trackDelta.getFlags() & IResourceDelta.CONTENT) != 0)
        {
           // TODO handle change
        }
     }
   }
}
```

`editFile` is the `IFile` the editor is working with.

You need to be careful how to handle the change because this will be invoked during the Save operation for the editor.

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get resource change events? Note: the event will only happen when you Save the file in one of the editors.

Comment: @greg_449 Actually we have implemented a editor with ctabFolder and showing report in it is not editable I am looking for the event as eclipse editors reflect means when backgroung data chnages it should reflect at ctabfolder too, i know it has to be done by reourcechangelistener but how in my case dnt know tried a lot of way.